# Scala: function/method application and tuples

Tags: scala, scala-2.8

I stumbled across a pretty interesting behavior in Scala.

```
scala> def foo(t: (Int, Int, Int)): Int = t._1 
foo: (t: (Int, Int, Int))Int

scala> foo(1,2,3)
res23: Int = 1

scala> foo((1,2,3))
res24: Int = 1
```

This also works the other way round:

```
scala> Some(1,2,3,4,5)     
res31: Some[(Int, Int, Int, Int, Int)] = Some((1,2,3,4,5))
```

While this sugar is extremely useful I did not find any documentation concerning this. So my question is basically: Where is this documented in the Scala Language Specification, and what other implications does this have if any.

Regards,
raichoo

Comment: Isn't `(((1,2,3)))` just parens around parens around a tuple?

Comment: Agreed, forget about the last 2 foos :) Update: removed them

Comment: Take a look at the answer provided by retronym to this question 2850902 from May last year which provides some details. Other consequences are also discussed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is known a Automatic Tupling. I [lodged a bug](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/3583) against the language specification, which is silent on this matter.

Here's the relevant part of the [compiler source code.](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_8_1_final/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/typechecker/Infer.scala#L751)